# Truncate Text - React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, truncate

I have a React Native app with a FlatList.

My logic that I have added was whenever the Character at 100th position is not empty an Expand/Collapse arrow should be added as shown below. NO arrow icon for short messages.

Well, this is bad logic!! Now when I change my app font to Large/small this logic won't work. It doesn't work for Chinese characters too LOL. So it shouldn't be based on number of characters.

```
{  alert.charAt(100) !== "" ?
                arrowClicked === true ? 
                <Icon type='materialicons' name='arrow-drop-up' onPress={()=>{this.setFullLength()}}  />
                : 
                <Icon type='materialicons' name='arrow-drop-down' onPress={()=>{this.setFullLength()}}  />
                : null
            }
```

It should detect that the text is long and being truncated. How can I implement this?? Please Help!!!!

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: noo. For "font:normal" I can do this. Now I change font to "large" then this won't work right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the onTextLayout and decide the line length using something like below.

```
function CustomText(props) {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = React.useState(false);
  const [lines, setLines] = React.useState(props.numberOfLines);

  const onTextLayout = (e) => {
    setShowMore(
      e.nativeEvent.lines.length > props.numberOfLines && lines !== 0
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text numberOfLines={lines} onTextLayout={onTextLayout}>
        {props.children}
      </Text>
      {showMore && (
        <Button title="Show More"
          onPress={() => {
            setLines(0);
            setShowMore(false);
          }}
        />
      )}
      {!showMore && (
        <Button title="Hide More"
          onPress={() => {
            setLines(props.numberOfLines);
          }}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Usage

```
  const text =
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to mak';

 <CustomText numberOfLines={2}>{text}</CustomText>
```

You can pass other props like styles as well.

Comment: This is great!!! But this will display "ShowMore" and "hide more" for every line. It should be shown only for long messages and not short messages. How do I restrict that??

Comment: Did you change the numberOfLines ?

Comment: numberOfLines={3}. suppose I have 2 messages. one message is just 1 line. second message is long like 10lines. "show more" feature should be displayed only for long message. (this is my company's requirement not mine LOL)

Comment: Ah you can put a logic on displaying the buttons

Comment: Also if you are sure on the line count being one go for the normal text

Comment: ok played around with it and it worked. Thanksss as always :)

Comment: You are welcome, hope you can mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers , and by [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the most helpful answer to any question you ask