# how numberOfLines work in react native Text component?

Tags: react-native, text

as the doc says: [ellipsizemode](https://reactnative.cn/docs/text#ellipsizemode) props defines how text will be truncated. in my case, i want to show a expand button instead of ellipsis glyph, and i could expand the text to show all of them by press the button.

so i want to figure out how `numberOfLines` actually works in  Text component in react-native. then i could archive this, anyone could help?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62317088/1435722

Comment: Take a look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632169/7581249)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will show your content in `<Text>` component which is fitted in those `numberOfLines`.

With output you are expecting or want to perform, you can use dynamic `numberOfLines` using `state`.

Just have that `state` variable default value of `lineNumbers` and change it when pressing on button or any other component.

```
this.state = {
    lineNumbers: 2
}
```

This indicates your numberOfLines will be default 2, and once user press on button or read more

```
this.setState({lineNumbers: null})
```

It will show whole content.

```
<Text numberOfLines={this.state.lineNumbers}>
```

Comment: when text is less than 2 line , i don't  want to show a expand button, how could i get this?

Comment: that is to say, i only want to show the read more button when text is more than 2 lines

Comment: Well for that you have to look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632169/3134215), it might be useful